# Due to a broken monitor, I need move my screen to the left

Tags: linux, xrandr, display

A fraction of the right side of my laptop screen is broken, in order to use only the good part the resolution needs to be about 1280x1024, aligned to the left.

A simple xrandr -s 1274x1080 will get the right resolution, but centered. Using --transform 1.2,0,323,0,1,0,0,0,1 will move the screen but not in the way I want. 
About 1/5 of the right side of the screen is broken. How can I make the screen move to the left?

Comment: how about doing it with the monitor buttons?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Because if it's a digital connection to a digital monitor then there are no positioning controls.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to achieve this with `xrandr`, but in case you are using `nvidia`, this is easy using `nvidia-settings`: [image: NVIDIA X Server Settings with viewport configured smaller than screen]
A a black border will be displayed at the right side of the viewport. I actually use this for projectors which may not use their entire projection region due to obstacles.

Comment: Hey there, my nvidia-settings only has 3 available options: Selection, Color Depth and Meta Mode. Doesn't have any of the ohers in your version, what do I do?

Comment: You may need to toggle the Basic… / Advanced… button.